# Implementating Showdown.js markdown parser on the server side for ColdFusion

Tags: java, parsing, coldfusion, markdown

This is a "fact finding" question to see how difficult it would be to create a ColdFusion UDF to parse markdown on the server using the [showdown.js parser.](http://attacklab.net/showdown/) There is already a java implementation that utilizes showdown.js (see code at the end of this post) and I want to see how to go about implementing it for ColdFusion. I have no experience in Java and I would not particularly call myself "a programmer," but I don't want this to stop me from trying.

**Summary**

I would like to run [Shadown.js](http://attacklab.net/showdown/) server-side in order to convert markdown to HTML.

**Why?**

Saving two versions of a user entry, one in markdown format and another in HTML, allows us to display the raw markdown version to the end user in case they wanted to edit their entry.

**Why not use a server-side parser?**

For two reasons:

1. As of now there are no ColdFusion markdown parsers for this specific purpose
2. Using Showdown.js on the client-side, and then a different parser on the server-side will result in inconsistent markup between the preview displayed to the client and the version stored in the database. Given that markdown is loosely defined, most parser implementations will have subtle differences.

There is [a very good blog entry](http://briancarper.net/blog/415/clojure-and-markdown-and-javascript-and-java-and) that discusses the issue.

**Why not do all the parsing on the client-side and post both versions?**

This does not strike me as a secure solution. I also think users would potentially be able to post markdown with HTML that does not match.

**Are there any existing implementations?**

There is [one implementation called CFShowdown](http://blog.adampresley.com/software-development/cfshowdown-a-markdown-library-for-coldfusion/comment-page-1/#comment-8029), but it's not for this specific purpose. Rather, it's for handling output on a page. The comments section of the [aforementioned blog](http://briancarper.net/blog/415/clojure-and-markdown-and-javascript-and-java-and) features a pure Java implementation written by a user called David:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = manager.getEngineByName("js");
try
{
    jsEngine.eval(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("showdown.js")));
    showdownConverter = jsEngine.eval("new Showdown.converter()");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error("could not create showdown converter", e);
}

try
{
    return ((Invocable) jsEngine).invokeMethod(
        showdownConverter, 
        "makeHtml", 
        markdownString
    ) + "";
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.error("error while converting markdown to html", e);
    return "[could not convert input]";
}
```

**Objective**

Create a java class that would allow us to use this implementation with a ColdFusion UDF or a custom tag inside a component, something along the lines of `<cfset html = getMarkdown(string)>`

Since I have no experience with Java, I want to get some advice and input from users on where and how to start going about this task. I created a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have files [showdown.js](http://attacklab.net/showdown/showdown-v0.9.zip) and a file markdown.txt (example below) in the same directory.

**showdown.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
manager = createObject("java", "javax.script.ScriptEngineManager").init();
jsEngine = manager.getEngineByName("js");

showdownJS = fileRead('#getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())#/showdown.js');

jsEngine.eval(showdownJS);
showdownConverter = jsEngine.eval("new Showdown.converter()");

markdownString = fileRead("#getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())#/markdown.txt");

args = [markdownString];

result = jsEngine.invokeMethod(
    showdownConverter,
    "makeHtml",
    args
) & "";
</cfscript>
```

**markdown.txt**

```
Showdown Demo
-------------

You can try out Showdown on this page:

  - Type some [Markdown] text on the left side.
  - See the corresponding HTML on the right.

For a Markdown cheat-sheet, switch the right-hand window from *Preview* to *Syntax Guide*.

Showdown is a JavaScript port of the original Perl version of Markdown.  You can get the full [source code] by clicking on the version number at the bottom of the page.

Also check out [WMD, the Wysiwym Markdown Editor][wmd].  It'll be open source soon; email me at the address below if you'd like to help me test the standalone version.

**Start with a [blank page] or edit this document in the left window.**

  [Markdown]: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
  [source code]: http://attacklab.net/showdown/showdown-v0.9.zip
  [wmd]: http://wmd-editor.com/
  [blank page]: ?blank=1 "Clear all text"
```

**Update**

Here's a version that takes [Adam Presley's work in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600535/implementating-showdown-js-markdown-parser-on-the-server-side-for-coldfusion/4605963#4605963) and does it all in a CFC. Note I took that little bit of magic he added at the end of showdown.js and put it into a CFC function whose return value is appended (i.e. `showdownAdapterJS()`).

CFC

```
<cfcomponent output="false" accessors="true">
    <cffunction name="init" output="false" access="public" returntype="Showdown" hint="Constructor">
        <cfset variables.manager = createObject("java", "javax.script.ScriptEngineManager").init()>
        <cfset variables.engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript")>
        <cfreturn this/>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="toHTML" output="false" access="public" returntype="any" hint="">
        <cfargument name="markdownText" type="string" required="true"/>
        <cfset var local = structNew()/>
        <cfset var bindings = variables.engine.createBindings()>
        <cfset var result = "">

        <cftry>
            <cfset bindings.put("markdownText", arguments.markdownText)>
            <cfset variables.engine.setBindings(bindings, createObject("java", "javax.script.ScriptContext").ENGINE_SCOPE)>
            <cfset var showdownJS = fileRead('#getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())#/showdown.js')>
            <cfset showdownJS &= showdownAdapterJS()>
            <cfset result = engine.eval(showdownJS)>
            <cfcatch type="javax.script.ScriptException">
                <cfset result = "The script had an error: " & cfcatch.Message>
            </cfcatch>
        </cftry>

        <cfreturn result>
    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="showdownAdapterJS" output="false" access="private" returntype="string" hint="">
        <cfset var local = structNew()/>
<cfsavecontent variable="local.javascript">
<cfoutput>#chr(13)##chr(10)#var __converter = new Showdown.converter();
__converter.makeHtml(markdownText);</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
        <cfreturn local.javascript>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Usage

```
<cfset showdown = createObject("component", "Showdown").init()>
<cfset markdownString = fileRead("#getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())#/markdown.txt")>
<cfoutput>#showdown.toHTML(markdownString)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: THIS IS AWESOME! I'm going to try and bundle it up into a component plugin for CFWheels! Is this threat safe in it's current form?

Comment: I don't know. Think this has more to do with showdown.js. When I look through Showdown.js code there are references to global variables (i.e. shared state) such as `g_urls`, so I'm guessing it's not. However, if a new instance of Showdown (i.e. `new Showdown.convert()`) is created every time I imagine that *might* be thread safe.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you explain a little bit of your code in the CFC part? Specifically the binding part. I don't quite understand what's going on there. Also, why not stick the showdown.js file in the variables scope instead of calling it out each single time?

Answer (score 3):

You can run server-side javascript in CF by using CFGroovy - which basically allows you to run any JSR-223 scripting language inline with CFML.

Ben Nadel has an [example of running server-side javascript using CFGroovy and Rhino](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1766-Running-Javascript-In-ColdFusion-With-CFGroovy-And-Rhino.htm)

The example has everything you need - assuming you have the javascript code already put together.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I've already wrapped up Showdown in a Java library that can be used in ColdFusion. The example I provide, in what I admit is poor documentation, uses a custom tag, but you can use the Java component just as easily like so.

```
<cfset obj = createObject('java', 'com.adampresley.cfshowdown.Showdown').init() />
<cfset parsedText = obj.toHTML(trim(someMarkdownContent)) />
```

Perhaps that helps? Either way, long live Markdown! :)

Comment: See my update for a ColdFusion only solution that you could easily swap out to make work with the custom tag you've got.

Answer (score 1):

Given that Markdown is not a regular language, and a majority of implementations are a series of regular expressions, there are bound to be differences between them, as you noted. There is almost no avoiding it.

If your objective is just to:

1. Provide a client-side markdown editor with live-preview (like the Stack Overflow question/answer editor), and
2. Store an identically-processed copy of the generated html for end-user display

Then I see only two real options:

1. Do all markdown processing server-side, and accomplish your preview using AJAX to submit the markdown and get the updated preview html (using the same library that you'll ultimately use to generate the stored html), or
2. Do all markdown processing client-side, and submit ***both*** the raw markdown and the generated HTML as parts of your content composition form and store both; so that you can display the original markdown for editing purposes and the generated HTML for display purposes.

Personally I would go with option 2.

Comment: Adam, for some reason I just don't feel comfortable sending two versions from the client side. Also, If JS was disabled it could potentially create a mess!

Comment: What's wrong with sending 2 versions from client side? You're already sending 1 and converting it, so you obviously trust the markdown... And if JS is disabled on the client side then the editor won't be of much use anyway.

Comment: I thought one of the advantages of Markdown was to avoid injecting arbitrary HTML leading to Cross-site scripting attacks.  That's completely bypassed if you let the browser to do the Markdown-to-HTML conversion.... be prepared to be hacked.

Comment: @user9876, I think this is only true if you don't sanitize the HTML before it's sent to the database. I imagine you would always need to sanitize regardless of the format; markdown or otherwise, you can't prevent a user from inserting malicious code into the textarea.

Comment: Markdown allows for pass-through HTML, so sanitization and/or trust is a requirement from the beginning.